# CoreData renaming relationship on mapping

Tags: xcode, cocoa, core-data, osx-snow-leopard

I have this coredata model in two different versions. All I changed is the name of a relationship.

But it seems insanely impossible to rename it using a simple mapping model!

Lets say I have the entity Foo and Bar, and a to-many relationship from Foo to Bar called "mane" and a reverse relationship from Bar to Foo called "padme". I want to change "padme" to "hum".

In the **mapping model inspector** I have:

```
Key Path:     $source.padme
Mapping Name: FooToFoo
```

In the **relationship mappings** I have:

```
Destination Relationship: hum
Value expression:
FUNCTION(
  $manager,
  "destinationInstancesForEntityMappingNamed:sourceInstances:" ,
  "FooToFoo",
  $source.padme
)
```

Any thoughts?